# Can't get a Pterodactyl node to start when using a port forwarded panel

Tags: linux, server, system, minecraft, system-administration

I have a dedicated server that I run at home. I'm trying to port forward the pterodactyl panel but now I can't get the node to run.
I created a new node with FQDM as the public ip of the panel, which can be viewed from the public ip of the server followed by port 443. Then I do the command to change the config file, and I'm using the public ip of the server.
cd /etc/pterodactyl && sudo wings configure --panel-url http://public_ip --token token_here --node 3

Now the node has the red heart next to it, even when I changed the daemon and SFTP port to be unique. When I use the local IP, it all works but only on the local ip of the node, which shows that the server itself is working.
Anyone have any insight on this?